# redirect to a page and method from a different controller after the devise log in

Tags: ruby, redirect, authentication, devise

After the successful devise login I need to redirect to a specific view called companyshow, that is located in a views/companies/companyshow. I also have a method for this view in companies controller, by the same name. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 'some_url'
end
```